# ternary operator inside of Array.map return first true condition

Tags: reactjs

How can I return the first value that equates to true when mapping through objects in an array.

for instance

```
results.map((item) => {
 return item.type == "x" ? 
   <iframe
   src={item.key}
   /> :
  null
})
```

in my particular case if I console.log item.key i get 3 different values which is the correct number of objects that have a type that equal "x" how can i return only the first value that equates to true? something like item[0].key is returning undefined.

Comment: `results.find((item) => item.type === "x")`

Comment: what about `Array.prototype.filter`?

Comment: `<iframe src={results.find(({ type }) => type === "x")} />`

Answer (score 0):

Item[0] returns null because you use it inside the array loop. So you check every item and if the item is not an array it will not work. `Array.find` is better in your use case instead of a map.

I would use:

```js
const firstx = results.find((item) => item.type === 'x');

if (firstx) {
  return <iframe src={item.key} />;
} else {
  return null;
}
```